# Scan part of Brother DCP L2550DN (and possibly other Brother scan) not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, scanner, brother

Even with the  [Brother own drivers installed](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=fr&lang=fr&prod=dcpl2550dn_eu&os=128&flang=English), the scan part of "Brother DCP L2550DN" is not working (scan not found, sometimes even scanning but returning an error) on simple-scan or xsane in Ubuntu 20.04, while it was working on earlier versions.

(Note that this is a solved question, posted for others to get the solution quickly)

Answer (score 0):

Brother released a "patch" deb specific for Ubuntu 20.04 (and derivatives) that solves the problem (possibly related to [this bug](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/g9eykh/brother_scanner_driver/)):

https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=hll6300dw_eu&ftype3=100257&faqid=faq00100729_000

Note: While personally tested on DCP L2550DN, this solution should also apply to other Brother multifunction printer/scanners, like e.g. HL-L6300DW(T)